# Streaming turned on by default on Camel CXF Server on PAYLOAD mode

Tags: streaming, cxf, apache-camel, payload

In the class org.apache.camel.component.cxf.feature.PayLoadDataFormatFeature, allowStreaming is enabled by default. This will set the MessagePart type to DOMSource or Source by default for PAYLOAD mode.

```
static {

        String s = System.getProperty("org.apache.camel.component.cxf.streaming");
        DEFAULT_ALLOW_STREAMING = s == null || Boolean.parseBoolean(s);
    }

    boolean allowStreaming = DEFAULT_ALLOW_STREAMING;
```

So it looks like to turn off this behavior, allowStreaming=false should be explicitly set on the CxfEndpoint. Just want to know if this is by design? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use allowStreaming option to override the default setting.